# readr::write_csv and utils::write.csv not writing full dataset

Tags: r, export-to-excel, import-from-csv, readr

I've got a dataset with 127,122 rows of data and 19 columns. I read in the data using `readr::read_csv` and specified the columns all be character format. The data loads without any warning to call `problems(...)` to see what might have gone wrong. `dim` shows the appropriate shape of the database and all values appear to be correct. However, when I use `write.csv` or `write_csv`, the results are not as expected. When I open the file in Excel, the number of rows varies between 95,000 and 110,000 and the column headers are not included in the output file. Any idea as to what might be going on?

Here is some additional information that might be helpful:

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info 
---------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252
Packages 
--------------------------------------
 package    * version date       source        
 assertthat   0.1     2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 colorspace   1.2-6   2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 curl         0.9.2   2015-08-08 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 DBI          0.3.1   2014-09-24 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 devtools     1.8.0   2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 digest       0.6.8   2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 dplyr      * 0.4.2   2015-06-16 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 ggplot2    * 1.0.1   2015-03-17 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 git2r        0.11.0  2015-08-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 gtable       0.1.2   2012-12-05 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 igraph     * 1.0.1   2015-06-26 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 lazyeval     0.1.10  2015-01-02 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 magrittr   * 1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 MASS         7.3-43  2015-07-16 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 memoise      0.2.1   2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 munsell      0.4.2   2013-07-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 plyr         1.8.3   2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 proto        0.3-10  2012-12-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 R6           2.1.0   2015-07-04 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 Rcpp         0.12.0  2015-07-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 readr      * 0.1.1   2015-05-29 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 reshape2     1.4.1   2014-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 rversions    1.0.2   2015-07-13 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 scales       0.2.5   2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 stringi      0.5-5   2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 stringr    * 1.0.0   2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 xml2         0.1.1   2015-06-02 CRAN (R 3.2.2)

> class(dat)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> dim(dat)
[1] 127122     19
```

Comment: So apparently it's not R that is messing up, it's Excel. `read_csv("C:/file/to/path/file.csv")` loads in the file I saved and it has the same shape. Even opening it in a text editor shows all of the right data. So why would the file not play well with Excel?

Comment: How did you open it in Excel? I suspect your data has some hidden tabs or such like.